# CSS animation with squares

Tags: css, css-animations

So recently I had my exams and unfortunately failed because of CSS animation. One of the tasks was to make CSS animation with the squares.

I can't remember the exact question and task but it was like this:

> - Make three squares and let the first one go for 2 seconds to the right
> - Wait for the second square to do the same thing, without returning back.
> - The third one should do the same thing
> - After the third square touches the right side, they all should go back to the first place.

Does anyone have an idea how I can make squares to go back to the first place?

```css
.row {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}


.row div {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;

}

#first {
  animation: first 2s linear forwards 0ms,
  back 2s linear alternate 5s;

}

#second {
  animation: first 2s linear forwards 2s;
}

#third {
  animation: first 2s linear forwards 4s;
}

@keyframes first {
  0% {
    left: 0;

  }

  100% {
    left: 100%;

  }
}

@keyframes back {
  0% {
    right: 0%;

  }

  100% {
    right: 100%;

  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Animation testing</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="row">
      <div id="first"></div>
    
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div id="second"></div>
     
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div id="third"></div>
      
    </div>
    

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: *"2 seconds to the right"*....  than why you use `5s` ?

Comment: From your question: *"and wait for the second square to do the same thing"* means exactly that the first and the second do the **exact same thing**: they both start at the same time and they both end at the same time. And since you also mentioned that the third one does the same thing - actually they all do the same thing. You never mentioned one square should wait for another to finish its *to-right* animation. That simple. ...Or you misunderstood the task you you missed to explain it well.

Comment: The way you show the question lacks enough detail for it to be answered - for example when does the second square start to move and how long does it take to get to the destination? Once you know all that information you can set the CSS keyframes so that say the first square moves for m% of the total time, then stays in the same position for s% of the time (while the others do their moving).

Comment: @AHaworth Exactly. I need a way how to make the animation stay in the same position for s% of the time, and wait for the second square to reach the end. What code should I use for that?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I fixed the example, can you check it out? The question is, how can I make squares go back to the first place after they hit the right side of the page?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting task. Today I learned something. Actually my first animation ever :)

To move the squares to the right:

- I have used your existing and already correctly working `first`, `second`, and `third` keyframes with the same timings.
- The first starts at 0s and  takes 2 seconds, the second starts after two seconds and takes two seconds, so the third after 4 seconds.

To return the squares:

- I have defined another `back` keyframe.
- To start the `back` keyframe, I have added `back 2s linear forwards 6s` to all elements as a second animation.

The second animation takes 2 seconds and starts after 6 seconds when all others are finished (3 * 2 seconds each).

Note: You could also reverse the positions in the `back` keyframe and use one of the alternatives to `forwards` instead, see https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp.

```css
.row {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.row div {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}

#first {
  animation: first 2s linear forwards 0s,
  back 2s linear forwards 6s;
}

#second {
  animation: second 2s linear forwards 2s,
  back 2s linear forwards 6s;
}

#third {
  animation: third 2s linear forwards 4s,
  back 2s linear forwards 6s;
}

@keyframes first {
  0% {
    left: 0;
  }

  100% {
    left: 100%;
  }
}

@keyframes second{
  0% {
    left: 0;
  }

  100% {
    left: 100%;
  }
}

@keyframes third{
  0% {
    left: 0;
  }

  100% {
    left: 100%;
  }
}

@keyframes back{
  0% {
    left: 100%;
  }

  100% {
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Animation testing</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="row">
      <div id="first"></div>
    
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div id="second"></div>
     
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div id="third"></div>
      
    </div>
    

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this, it may work.

```css
.move-me {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
.move-me-1 {
  animation: move-in-steps 8s steps(4) infinite;
}
.move-me-2 {
  animation: move-in-steps 8s steps(4, start) infinite;
}
.move-me-3 {
  animation: move-in-steps 8s infinite;
}

body {
  padding: 20px;
}

@keyframes move-in-steps {
  0% {
    left: 0;
    background: blue;
  }
  100% {
    left: 100%;
    background: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="move-me move-me-1">steps(4, end)</div>
<br>
<div class="move-me move-me-2">steps(4, start)</div>
<br>
<div class="move-me move-me-3">no steps</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you use some [foreign resources](https://css-tricks.com/using-multi-step-animations-transitions/) scraped from other authors, please, provide the necessary kudos/link-to-resources to the Original Authors. Otherwise gain 50 reputation points in order to post a comment with link to OP in the **comments section** as a commentary/suggestion. A *"This might help you!"* or *"See this code I found online!"*-answers are not in the expected quality format for this site.